# Как работать со справочниками в одной таблице?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Кто знает как по-научному (в идеале, на английском) называется система хранения справочников в одной таблице? Ну то есть когда и "Пол", и "Профессии", и "Цвета", например, хранятся не каждый в своей табличке, а все в одной. Хочу найти как-то теоретический материал как работать с такой таблицей, как заполнять значениями, как организовать parent-child relationship, если присутствуют еще натуральные ключи.

Comment: EAV что ли ? ...

Comment: в cms всяких нечто из подобного таксономии называется

Answer (score -2):

Чаще всего используют типа union_statement.

--Использую pl/sql Oracle

Создается таблица с рабочим названием и триггер.
Например : union_statement, union_statement_trg

Создается 5 столбцов в первой таблице.

```
CREATE TABLE union_statement

    (
    ID number(10) not null, -- id понятно
    Value varchar(500) not null, -- название значения
    Value_column varchar(500), -- характеристика значения(может быть null)
    Version_nomer varchar(500) not null, -- номер версии
    date_column date not null, -- дата вставки значения 
    user_name varchar(500) --имя внесшего изменения
    )
    on commit preserve rows;
```

Это основа для нашего справочника. Можете переделать его под своё усмотрение, но в общем случае данная конструкция не нуждается в правке

Создается триггер, нужен для установлении даты изменения/внесения справочника и имя рабочей сессии изменябщего/добавляющего значения

```
create or replace trigger union_statement_trg -- создаем триггер
before insert or update on union_statement -- перед вставкой в таблицу
for each now

begin 
  if :new.date_column is null then -- если значение даты не установлено
   select systimestamp into :new.date_column from dual; -- вставляем дату
  end if;
and;
  if :new.user_name is null then; -- если не указан изменяющий
   select user into :new.user_name from dual;  -- вставляем имя
  end if;
end;
```

Можно и ручками, но так быстрее(имхо)
Можно так же добавить в триггер автоматическое установление версии добавив еще одно условие

```
and 
  if :new.version_nomer is null then -- если версия не указана
   set version_nomer = version_nomer +1 -- вставляем + 1 в версию
end if;
```

Работа с такой таблицей зависит от колличества обращающихся. Возможны моменты, когда начнет отваливаться интеграция в таблицу из-за того, что несколько участников обращаются к этой таблице. Это необходимо учесть.

Добавление данных в таблицу возможно простым insert'om, но, если интересно внесение через java постучи в лс.

Надеюсь я правильно ответил на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Вы о чём? Приведите пример.

Comment: Ответ в текущем виде неподробен и непонятен